# Calander table properties in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to develop a page like this, I have made some of this page kindly review my code and help me to complete this page thanks, help me in developing that line which is pointed from date to circle avatar and also the remaining things.

```
**Code:**
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:femi/screens/drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import '../utils.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
final Set<DateTime> _selectedDays = LinkedHashSet<DateTime>(
equals: isSameDay,
hashCode: getHashCode,
);
DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
void _onDaySelected(DateTime selectedDay, DateTime focusedDay) {
setState(() {
  _focusedDay = focusedDay;
  // Update values in a Set
  if (_selectedDays.contains(selectedDay)) {
    _selectedDays.remove(selectedDay);
  } else {
    if (_selectedDays.length >= 5) {
      _selectedDays.remove(5);
    } else {
      _selectedDays.add(selectedDay);
    }
  }
});

// _selectedEvents.value = _getEventsForDays(_selectedDays);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  // drawer: Drawer(),
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0,
    toolbarHeight: 50,
    titleSpacing: 60,
    leading: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DrawerScreen()));
      },
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.menu_rounded,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
    title: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Period Calender',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
        ),
        IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded,
              color: Colors.black,
            ))
      ],
    ),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.notifications_none_rounded,
            color: Colors.black,
          ))
    ],
  ),
  body: ListView(

    children: [
      TableCalendar(
        firstDay: DateTime.utc(2010, 10, 16),
        lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 3, 14),
        focusedDay: _focusedDay,
        // rangeStartDay: _rangeStart,
        // rangeEndDay: _rangeEnd,
        // rangeSelectionMode: _rangeSelectionMode,
        headerVisible: false,
        calendarFormat: CalendarFormat.week,
        selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
          // Use values from Set to mark multiple days as selected
          return _selectedDays.contains(day);
        },
        // selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
        //   return isSameDay(_selectedDay, day);
        // },
        onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
        // onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
        //   if (!isSameDay(_selectedDay, selectedDay)) {
        //     setState(() {
        //       _selectedDay = selectedDay;
        //       _focusedDay = focusedDay;

        //       // _rangeSelectionMode = RangeSelectionMode.toggledOff;
        //     });
        //   }
        // },
        // onRangeSelected: (start, end, focusedDay) {
        //   setState(() {
        //     // _selectedDay = null;
        //     _focusedDay = focusedDay;
        //     _rangeStart = start;
        //     _rangeEnd = end;
        //     _rangeSelectionMode = RangeSelectionMode.toggledOn;
        //   });
        // },
      ),
      Stack(
        children: [
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(90,20),
            child: Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      'images/circle.png',
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 110,
            top: 40,
            child: Container(
              height: 160,
              width: 160,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    blurRadius: 15,
                    spreadRadius: 3
                  )
                ],

                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Color.fromRGBO(249, 168, 149, 1),
                    Color.fromRGBO(244, 91, 60, 1),

                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  stops: [0.1, 0.5,],
                ),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              //  border: Border.all(),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 30),
                  Text(
                    'Ovulation in',style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,

                  ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '5 days',style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 19
                  ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'High chances of getting pregnant',style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 12

                  ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 50),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28),
        child: Text(
          'Daily Femi Facts',
          textScaleFactor: 1.3,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 170,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Container(

            height: 40,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30,top: 20),
            width: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              border: Border.all(
                  width: 2,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(115, 108, 178, 1))
            ),

          ),
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 0.5),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        child: const ListTile(
          title: Text('testing'),
          leading: CircleAvatar(),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 0.5),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        child: const ListTile(
          title: Text('testing'),
          leading: CircleAvatar(),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 0.5),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
        child: const ListTile(
          title: Text('testing'),
          leading: CircleAvatar(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What's the relation between the non-functional gauge and the calendar? If it's just the line connecting the two then I'd say that effort will be wasted on a bad design.

Check out this package:  [syncfusion_flutter_gauges](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_gauges)
You can make highly customizable gauges

Check out this shot from Dribble [Menstruation Cycle](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1351062/screenshots/8899543/media/b70cd7deb43c978643e782a178735583.mp4)

[image]